# Do you say 'any change which~'?

Tags: grammar

'any change that ~' is usually heard. What about 'any + noun + relative pronoun which'?

For example, in the following sentence "Any product that includes more than 15 per cent of the daily recommended intake of each ingredient will get a label."  Is it acceptable to replace that with which?

Comment: You want that here. No need for which here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good explanation on the rules and differences between *that* and *which*: [Read here.](https://www.writingforward.com/grammar/grammar-rules/that-and-which)

It all basically boils down to this quote from the article:

> If you need the clause to maintain a sentence’s meaning, then use *that*.

The clause in your example sentence is here in bold:
*"Any product **that includes more than 15 per cent of the daily recommended intake of each ingredient** will get a label."*

If we can remove the clause and the sentence still holds its meaning, then we should use *which*.

If removing the clause changes the sentence's meaning, then we should use *that*.

Here's your sentence with the clause removed:
    *"Any product will get a label."*
This changes the meaning of the sentence completely, so use *that*, not *which*.

---

One exception to this rule as stated in the same article is:

> - Which can be used restrictively when it’s preceded by a preposition.

"restrictively" refers to the clause being needed in the sentence.
So if you really want to use *which*, the acceptable sentence would become:

*"Any product **of which** includes more than 15 per cent of the daily recommended intake of each ingredient will get a label."*